# Quickblox auth error

Tags: android, quickblox

I'm getting this error when trying to login with user

```
[You have already logged in chat]
```

But when I make a request, I'm getting this logs :

```
D/QBASDK﹕ =========================================================
        === REQUEST ==== 5cf946b4-411e-4db0-a289-6f604537deec ===
        REQUEST
        GET https://api.quickblox.com/chat/Dialog.json
        HEADERS
        QuickBlox-REST-API-Version=0.1.1
        QB-SDK=Android 2.2.3
        QB-Token=***********
        PARAMETERS
        type=1
        INLINE
        GET https://api.quickblox.com/chat/Dialog.json?type=1
    08-10 15:33:53.042    3316-3316/ru.uruydasdev D/QBASDK﹕ *********************************************************
        *** RESPONSE *** 5cf946b4-411e-4db0-a289-6f604537deec ***
        STATUS : 422
        HEADERS
        Access-Control-Allow-Origin=*
        Cache-Control=no-cache
        Connection=keep-alive
        Content-Length=45
        Content-Type=application/json; charset=utf-8
        Date=Mon, 10 Aug 2015 19:33:53 GMT
        QB-Token-ExpirationDate=2015-08-10 21:33:30 UTC
        QuickBlox-REST-API-Version=0.1.1
        Server=nginx/1.0.15
        Status=422 Unprocessable Entity
        X-Rack-Cache=miss
        X-Request-Id=****************
        X-Runtime=0.006819
        X-UA-Compatible=IE=Edge,chrome=1
        BODY
        '{"errors":{"base":["Forbidden. Need user."]}}'
```

Any Ideas? I can't understand how is this possible to get this errors in such sequence. *Removed token in case of security.*

Answer (score 0):

Thera are 2 kind of auth requests in QB:

1) REST API auth - ability to call REST API

2) Chat auth - real time communication channel

To be work with REST API (list chat dialogs for example), you have to login via Users module http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-users-android#Sign_In_.26_Social_authorization

Comment: I'm using QB Android SDK